# Firebird queries using chars/varchar

Tags: char, firebird, varchar

I am using SQLManager Lite for firebird and it was impossible so far to write a query which would do an operation on char/varchar columns. Character set is win1252.

A query like

```
select * from Person where name = 'John'
```

won't return any results despite the fact that the record exists in the database. A similar query on a numerical column works just fine. 
AM I am missing anything here?

Also, this query runs fine from my application. The only issue is that I would like to be able to run it within SQLManager Lite too. As a side note, values for char and varchar columns are not displayed properly within the same SQLManager Lite.

Comment: `char` columns are padded with spaces to the defined length (as required by the SQL standard). `varchar` is not. I can hardly see any reason to use `char` instead of `varchar`.

Comment: Even if the column is defined as char(1) the result will be the same.

Comment: What you mean by "not displayed properly"? What is shown if you select * from table for the record where the name is 'John'?

Comment: try this(select * from Person where name like 'John')

Comment: check out http://ms-sql-to-firebird.sharewarecentral.com/

Comment: A `char(1)` column cannot hold the value `'John'`

Comment: @jachguate: If I look at the data in the table I will see only the first character of that char/varchar field

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: my point was that it did not matter the length of the field. Be it varchar or char with length of 2048 or 1 the result is the same

Comment: Are you sure character set is win1252 (ansi) and not a unicode charset?

Comment: Please post a script with `create table`, `insert` and `select` statements that show the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to like

```
select * from Person where name like 'John'
```

Comment: What's the technical reason/idea behind this?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why this would work and `name = 'John'` wouldn't